# Añadir fila a tabla por id al pulsar un button en Jquery 1.11.3

Tags: jquery, tablas

Tengo el siguiente código que es cuando se pulsa un button se ejecuta la función de JQuery

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("button").click(function(){
  //Hemos pulsado un button 
  
  if ($(this).attr("id")){
   ...
    var idAnadir= "idA";
    var filasAnadir =$("#"+idAnadir)
    var idPadre ="idP";
    //Esto añade una fila y funciona
    //$("#"+idPadre).closest( "tr" ).after('<tr id="insertada"><td></td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td></td></tr>');
    
    //Sin embargo esto no sé porque no me funciona sin embargo aparentemente filasAnadir recupera datos (la fila entiendo)
    $("#"+idPadre).closest( "tr" ).after(filasAnadir);
```

Sin embargo no me funciona donde dice el comentario , pero si la añado manualmente sí

Answer (score 0):

al parecer no estas obteniendo bien  el contenido de las filas
obtenlo con $("#"+idAnadir).html();

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        //Hemos pulsado un button 

        if ($(this).attr("id")){
            ...
                var idAnadir= "idA";
                var filasAnadir =$("#"+idAnadir).html();
                var idPadre ="idP";
                //Esto añade una fila y funciona
                //$("#"+idPadre).closest( "tr" ).after('<tr id="insertada"><td></td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td></td></tr>');

                //Sin embargo esto no sé porque no me funciona sin embargo aparentemente filasAnadir recupera datos (la fila entiendo)
                $("#"+idPadre).closest( "tr" ).after(filasAnadir);
```

Comment: He probado eso y me devuelve un undefined. La tabla la tengo de la siguiente manera

<table id="tJor">
<thead>
 <tr>...
       </thead>
  <tbody>
                    <tr id="idA" display="block">